# Multiple find exec options: synology index command line

Tags: unix, find, exec, nas, synology

I want to index some files on my NAS after moving them in the correct folder.
My command would be something like :

```
find *.$ext -exec mv "{}" $path \; -exec synoindex -a $(echo $path)$(basename "{}") \;
```

The first part is working. All files with $ext extension are moved to destination $path.
But the second part, which is supposed to index these files in their new $path folder, does not work.

This is strange because :

- {} contains the right value => the complete old path of each file processed
  To make sure of that, I added a third part which only does : -exec echo {} \;
- Executing separately $(echo $path)$(basename "{}") works, after replacing {} by one real
  value taken for example => gives the the complete new path => syntax is correct
- Executing separately synoindex -a $(echo $path)$(basename "{}") works, after replacing {} by 
  one real value taken for example => command is correct

Thanks for any idea.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command substitutions `$(echo $path)` and `$(basename "{}")` are executed by your shell before `find` is executed. 
And you don't need to `echo` the `$path` variable. You could execute a small shell script instead:

```
find . -type f -name "*.$ext" -exec sh -c '
  targetpath=$1; shift # get the value of $path
  for file; do
    mv -i "$file" "$targetpath"
    synoindex -a "$targetpath/${file##*/}"
  done
' sh "$path" {} +
```

This starts `find` in the current directory `.` searching for regular files (`-type f`) ending with 
the file extension `$ext` (`-name "*.$ext"`)
and executes a small shell script passing the `$path` variable as first argument to the script. 
The following arguments are the filepaths found by `find`.

The parameter expansion `${file##*/}` removes the longest prefix `*/` from the file and the result is the basename. 
If your `$path` variable already contains a trailing slash `/`, then omit the `/` after `$targetpath`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will check your script.

Are you sure the commands $(echo $path) and $(basename "{}") are executed before the find because if do :

find . -name Benny.and.Joon.1993*.mp4 -exec echo string1 \; -exec echo string2 \;

i only have the results if find returns 0 :
string1
string2

which means he is executed first

Comment: Yes, `$(basename "{}")` immediately evaluates to `{}` and the second `-exec` is then run on the result of `$(echo $path){}` and this is only executed if the exit status of the first `-exec` is `0`. To debug my answer, you can add an `echo` before `mv` and `synoindex` to see what the commands would do.

Comment: Thanks, your script helped a lot